# Change backround color to oroginal in javascript

Tags: javascript, background, toggle

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="square extra" id="test"></div>
</div>

var color = document.getElementById('test');
function changeColor(){
color.style.background = "cornflowerblue";}

color.addEventListener('click', changeColor)
```

how do I reverse background color to original by pressing same div again?

Comment: What do you mean by original?

Comment: So default color is "cadetblue", by pressing <div> I change color to "cornflowerblue", and its stays active, so I would like to press same <div> again, and go back to default color of "cadetblue".

Comment: How is cadet blue defined on the div? A class? Inherited?

Comment: in css file:
.square {
background: cadetblue;
}

Comment: I ask because there could be many ways. `color.style.background = ''` could be one way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a class with the background color, then change the function to toggle the class.

See snippet below:

```js
var color = document.getElementById('test');

function changeColor() {
  color.classList.toggle(`bgCornflowerblue`);
}

color.addEventListener('click', changeColor)
```

```css
.square {
  background: CadetBlue;
  color:white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.bgCornflowerblue {
  background: Cornflowerblue!important
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square extra" id="test">Click me</div>
</div>
```